# Find the location of the bash executable on windows from python

Tags: python, windows, bash, shell, subprocess

I'm writing a program that executes short shell one liners (potentially including pipes and background tasks etc), and I'd like to make it "just work" cross platform as much as possible.

For mac/linux the following seems to work well:

```py
shell = os.environ.get("SHELL", "/bin/bash")
subprocess.Popen([shell, "-c", script_content])
```

However given that on windows:

1. `SHELL` isn't usually set
2. Assuming that bash is installed, a usable bash executable might be found in a variety of different places

What's the best way to make this work as reliably as possible in windows?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`?

And if you are doing cross platorm you could use `sys.platorm` to find the platform the user is using.

Comment: I don't think cmd.exe is what I want. Specifically I'd like to make one liners written for a POSIX shell (generally bash, but most bash lines will work in zsh, fish, tcsh, etc) that might look like `some-executable > /dev/null 2>&1 &;`. I figure on developer windows machines there's a reasonable chance of bash being available, I mostly just need to find it. My understanding is the cmd.exe generally won't work with the same syntax/semantic as a *nix shell.

Answer (score 0):

On Window, 'COMSPEC' holds the name of the current command program. You can write unconditional lookup to lookup in the environemnt. Usually, better to take this approach, as in many cases, python script may be executed from 'git-bash', WSL or similar. No need to explicitly program for specific platform.

1. First Using SHELL
2. If none, use COMSPEC

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMSPEC

Answer (score -1):

If you have Windows git client installed, you should have git bash, so in a CMD window:

```
set SHELL="c:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe"
```

then you can run you python program.